# In Numbers for Mac, possible to have custom formatting depending on value of other cell?

Tags: macos, iwork-numbers

I have several columns of numbers, and I want to highlight one of those with a background color.

I have created a single cell at the top of these columns, that for each column contains either a 1 (for highlight) or 0 (for normal).

Is it possible to create a custom formatting for the cells in each column that use the value from the top cell to determine if the formatting should take effect or not?

It seems that I can only create a custom format that uses the cell contents itself, not a different cell.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the tag "Numbers" as the tag "Number" already exists. In this case, "Numbers" is the product name, not "several numbers".

Comment: It's `iwork-numbers`, and questions about software shouldn't have the `mac` tag. Cheers!